# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bokeh' Many published solutions tried but failed

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, bokeh

I am not sure why but I am having difficulties getting bokeh running on my jupyter notebook. I tried pip instal bokeh, conda update bokeh but none of those worked for me.

These are the libraries I need:

```
import bokeh
import bokeh.io
bokeh.io.output_notebook()
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

The error states: ModuleNotFoundError                       
<ipython-input-35-0f0c4b610685> in <module>
----> 1 import bokeh
      2 import bokeh.io
      3 bokeh.io.output_notebook()
      4 from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
      5 from bokeh.models import HoverTool

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bokeh'
```

What other options do I have?

Comment: The environment you are running the notebook out of is not the same environment you installed Bokeh into.

Comment: @bigreddot I am not sure what I need to do...My notebook is local so I tried doing a pip install also locally I thought...please advise